# Character encoding - MySQL 5.1.67 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, centos

I've been looking for some hours for an answer for this one and it seems to be not yet covered.  I will try to be as succinct as possible.

I have a client running a web app with some character encoding problems.  Specifics:

- CentOS 6.3
- MySQL Server 5.1.67
- **ALL** tables set to UTF-8
- SHOW FULL COLUMNS verifies also that all text columns in each table are UTF-8
- Data going into database is UTF-8
- Data is served to web clients as UTF-8
- No bad characters in output data; forcing browser to Latin1 causes all manner of problems

So, basically, everything is UTF-8, and everything is working perfectly.

EXCEPT... all connections to MySQL **must be Latin1**, or else the whole system falls apart.  I have verified this with the console MySQL client, PHP/Mysql, PHP/Mysqli and the Ruby mysql gem v2.8.1.  Issuing a command like "SET NAMES utf8" or using the various API methods to change the connection character set to UTF-8 will cause all multibyte characters to become garbled and unrecognizable.

At the moment there is no major problem here, except of course that using a Latin1 connection to the server does not work at all in my Ubuntu test environment and so my programs keep breaking when I move them into production.  But I have a nagging feeling that something cannot possibly be right and it's going to come back and bite my client later on.

MySQL is reporting this upon initial connection to the server:

```
character_set_client: latin1
character_set_connection: latin1
character_set_database: latin1
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: latin1
character_set_server: latin1
character_set_system: utf8
```

And these are the settings that work for UTF-8 data.  If I change anything else to UTF-8, multi-byte characters die a miserable death.

If anybody has any idea what is going wrong here and where I can find any better documentation on it, that would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: If those settings work then obviously your data is not in UTF-8. For instance, when using PHP, strings are actually byte arrays and the burden of ensuring their encoding is on you. In other languages with more abstract strings, the driver will handle it.

Comment: While that would seem like an easy answer, I'm afraid you are incorrect here. There are various ways of verifying that the data in the tables is indeed UTF-8.For example, you might expect that somewhere along the line, some API or maybe MySQL itself was transcoding to Latin1 in each direction, thereby giving the illusion of UTF-8 data but actually storing it in Latin1.

Comment: However, if I do a test post with non-transcodeable characters (e.g. խ), MySQL's bit_length()/char_length() functions reveal that the multi-byte characters are intact, and the app will serve them correctly as UTF-8 later. If what you're suggesting was true, MySQL would see խ internally as ��, and yes, maybe PHP would be oblivious to this and simply serve the correct bytes in the correct order making it reappear later as UTF-8 data, but Ruby would know better, and MySQL would still show char_length() as 2, which it does not.

Comment: AND now having said all of that, it appears this is not always the case - I have managed to get char_length() to report an incorrect value for at least one test case. And I must point out that I wouldn't have investigated this possibility any further unless you had suggested it. Thank you!

Comment: Given that the db has gone through various phases and various admins over the years, and I came in well into the process, I'm starting to feel the "back away slowly" reaction setting in.

Comment: Cheers... nice monologue btw :D